# Percentage Over Column Total Calculation

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to do a cross table with a column that calculates the percentage the column total (third column from the left).  I've been trying to follow some examples found in my Google searches but can't seem to get it to work.

I tried to insert this custom expression in my subsets:
Count() THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows]))

But I get this error:  The expression is not valid after 'THEN' on line 1 character 9.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If someone still trying to do this you can do this :

```
Count() then Sum([Value]) Over (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows])) / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows])) as [Cumulative Sum]
```

That will give you this result :
[image]

Where you have "(Column Names)" in Horizontal, [country] in Vertical axis and the sum and cumulative sum in the Cell Values.